# Removing All Data from the Cache From Persistence in JEE5 Weblogic 10.3.5

Tags: java, jpa, weblogic-10.x, java-ee-5

I read that for clearing the JPA cache the next line is needed:

em.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll();

The problem I have is that my application is working in weblogic 10.3.5 and only works with JEE 5. What can I use in JEE 5 to do have the same functionality as the line before. When I try to used this line in weblogic It gives me this error:

*ERROR:javax/persistence/EntityManager.getEntityManagerFactory()Ljavax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/persistence/EntityManager.getEntityManagerFactory()Ljavax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory;*

Comment: Consequently you can conclude that the JPA API jar you use is inconsistent with the JPA implementation you are using. That method was added in JPA 2.0, so you have one of those as being JPA 1.0. Fix your dependencies. If stuck on JPA 1.0 then you would have to delve into the specifics of your JPA provider since there is no standard API call for getting the L2 cache before JPA 2

Comment: You're right. I was trying to find a similar way to do that for the upcoming months. In the long term the project is going be migrated to weblogic 12.2.1 and the problem shloud be solved. I think I will have to wait till then.